# Highlight duplicate cells in two column

Tags: excel, vba

I try to compare two columns and highlight text that found in both columns just and if column A contains any number more than once highlighted only same number in column b 
for ex. column A contains 13 ,13,13 and column B contains only 13 once SO highlight just 13 once in column A and the 13 once in b you can see the attached pic for more understanding thanks a lot in advanced

```
Sub Duplicate()
Dim myRange As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim myCell As Range
Set myRange = Range("A1:B100")
For Each myCell In myRange
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myRange, myCell.Value) > 1 Then
myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: The reason why you code is failing is that the count-if  counts instances in both Column A and Column B, why only 9 and 14 are left un-formatted as they only occur once throughout column A and B. Try to work out the logic first, and then write your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe there are a couple of mistakes in your example (12)?

I'm sure you can do this with CF, but I can't be bothered to try and work it out.

```
Sub Duplicate()

Dim myRange As Range
Dim count1 As Long, count2 As Long, i As Long
Dim myCell As Range
Dim rFind1 As Range, rFind2 As Range

Set myRange = Range("A1:B11")

For Each myCell In myRange.Columns(1).Cells                              'loop through each cell in column A
    count1 = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myRange.Columns(1), myCell.Value) 'number of times found in A
    count2 = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myRange.Columns(2), myCell.Value) 'number of times found in B
    If count2 > 0 Then                                                   'only do something if found in B
        Set rFind1 = myRange.Cells(myRange.Rows.count, 1)                'initialize Find at last cell of A
        Set rFind2 = myRange.Cells(myRange.Rows.count, 2)                'initialize Find at last cell of B
        For i = 1 To WorksheetFunction.Min(count1, count2)               'loop number of times found (lower of the 2 values)
            With myRange
                Set rFind1 = .Columns(1).Find(What:=myCell.Value, After:=rFind1, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                              SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'find the cell
                Set rFind2 = .Columns(2).Find(What:=myCell.Value, After:=rFind2)                              'find the matching cell in B
                rFind1.Interior.ColorIndex = 3                           'shade A
                rFind2.Interior.ColorIndex = 3                           'shade B
            End With
        Next i
    End If
Next myCell

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, sir for your answer .i test your code but the problem now column a contains 12,12 and  column b contains 12,12 you code highlighted just 12 once so i want to highlit them in both columns and if column a contains 13,13,13 and b 13,13  so i want to highlight two numbers in column a and two in b

Comment: So it's the number of times it's found in either column and the lower of those is the number which should be shaded in both columns?

Comment: Have re-jigged the code so please give it another try.

Comment: yes this is worked perfectly. thank you very very much sir